# Difference between getModel() , getSingleton() and getResourceModel()?

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

From many days I was searching the differences between getModel(), getResourceModel() and getSingleton(). But could not cleared up the facts. Could you please help over this ?

Which one is the best for magento optimization ?

Comment: What are you talking about? Give some code examples, class and path references.

Answer (score 1):

simply put:

- GetModel is used for busuiness logic, it retrieves a new instance from a class.
- getSingleton is same, except it retrieves a single existing object.
- getReosurceModel is used to interact with the database.

Those are not used for optimization, every Model has a different "meaning". I prefer instantiating every model once and then working with them. If you have a model with existing vars and values and you need them in the further course of programming, then you should make use of the singleton pattern.

HTH,

MageZeus